# Как в райдере убрать квадратную обводку вокруг редактируемого текста

Tags: c#, rider

Пробую райдер для написания C#. Постоянно выскакивает какой-то белый квадрат вокруг текста, который каждый раз приходится убирать эскейпом, чтобы он не умничал. Вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Облазил все настройки, но так и не смог понять, что это и зачем оно нужно. Появляется постоянно для параметров функций, для полей класса и так далее.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это отключить.

Comment: В Visual Studio такая же фича отвечает за переименование переменных. Пока оно выделено квадратиком, попробуйте вызвать контекстное меню и выбрать переименовать. Имя переменной заменится везде, где оно было использовано. Просто для удобства это сделано. В Visual Studio еще есть кнопки `Ctrl+.` которое вызывает контекстное меню рефакторинга.

Comment: @aepot я сначала тоже подумал про рефакторинг, но у соседнего параметра `y` контекстное меню одинаковое и без этого квадрата. А `enter` или пробел в этом квадрате ничего не дают, пробел вообще его расширяет на всю строку зачем-то. Ну и есть `Shift + F6` на любой переменной для удобного рефакторинга.

Comment: [Документация](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Refactorings__Rename.html#using-the-refactoring-for-different-c-entities)

Comment: @aepot спасибо. Понял хотя бы зачем это. Жаль отключить нельзя. Особенно надоедает в новом классе видеть эти квадраты когда ничего из написанного ещё не востребовано.

Comment: (дополню что в ссылке) это действительно для рефакторинга "постфактум", отключить нельзя, по крайней мере пока не нашел этого нигде. Если найдёте, напишите пожалуйста в коммент или в ответ.